# Incompatible library when running php 5.4.10

Tags: php

Currently there are two php versions on my system the built-in 5.3 and the homebrew version 5.4. Everything was fine after installing imagemagick via homebrew, the php 5.4 has been broken everytime when I type php keyword on terminal.

The error screen:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib
Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/php
Reason: Incompatible library version: php requires version 16.0.0 or later, but libfreetype.6.dylib provides version 13.0.0
```

The php 5.4 locates at `/usr/local/Cellar/php54/5.4.10`

Any idea how to fix it ? Thanks